# Sum of all even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, debugging, fibonacci

I'm trying to get the sum of all the even Fibonacci numbers. I can print the numbers out but I can't get the sum of them. This is in java.

```
class driver {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int a; 
        int b = 0;
        int c = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Finds fibonacci sequence
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;

            if ( c % 2 == 0) { // Check if it's even
                int sum = 0;
                sum = sum + c;
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the print statement outside the loop.

Comment: you keep setting the sum to `0` inside your loop every time you find an even, so effectively the code is simply `sum = c`. e.g. move the `int sum = 0` outside of the loop.

Comment: Look at where you're initializing ```sum```; step through the code yourself and see why that is a problem.

Comment: Even terms will just keep on coming, so the sum of all even fibonacci terms is infinity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not reinitialize the `sum` every time inside the loop, because that will cause it to lose the value it has. It should have its scope outside the `if` so that the same variable can be incremented each time.

```
class driver {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int a; 
        int b = 0;
        int c = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Finds fibonacci sequence
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;

            if (c % 2 == 0)  // Check if it's even
                sum += c;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives a negative number when you use 4 million

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int a; 
    int b = 0;
    int c = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Finds fibonacci sequence
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;

        if ( c % 2 == 0) { // Check if it's even
            sum += c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

You originally set sum = 0 every single time 'c' was an even number. This code should work as sum = 0 only before the process begins. This is actually a common mistake, but you will quickly learn that it is a bad idea.

Just so you know, I put the System.out.println(sum) statement outside of the loop so you don't have 10 different numbers as output.

Comment: When you use 4 million as the value for the fibonacci sequence, it gives you a negative number. This cannot be the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the integer variable sum, outside the for loop. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public final class eu_p002_sol {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println(new eu_p002_sol().run());  
    }  
public String run() {  
        int sum = 0;  
        for (int x = 0; ; x++) {  
            int fib = fibonacci(x);  
            if (fib > 4000000)  
                break;  
            if (fib % 2 == 0)  
                sum += fib;  
        }  
        return Integer.toString(sum);  
    }  

    private static int fibonacci(int n) {  
        if (n < 0 || n > 46)  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();  
        int a = 0;  
        int b = 1;  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
            int c = a + b;  
            a = b;  
            b = c;  
        }  
        return a;  
    }  
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone is still searching for a right answer:

```
static int sum = 0, seq = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    fib(1,2);

}

static void fib(int i, int j) {

    seq = j;
    if (seq <= 4000000) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            sum += j;
        }
        fib(j, i + j);
    } else {
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```